# How to create a horizontal/vertical tree in yEd Graph Editor?

Tags: mindmapping

I've been using yEd Graph Editor for the past few days (http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) and I wonder how to create a tree that looks like that: http://slickplan.com/create.php

I basically need a tree that mixes horizontal and vertical orientation.

The HVTreeLayouter (http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/api/y/layout/tree/HVTreeLayouter.html) seems to be able to do the trick, but I cannot figure how it actually works. I tried to add custom properties to the node but it doesn't do it.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try: menu Layout / Tree (Alt+Shift+T)
select Layout Style "Horizontal-Vertical"
and on "Directed" tab: Child Placement policy: "All leaves on the same level"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zmila, your answer isn't actually right but it got me into the right direction:
I had to user the Treelike Layout, Layout Style "Directed", and on "Directed" tab: Child Placement Policy: "Leaves stacked right".
Thanks again.